# How to put Google Business Updates on website

Tags: google, google-business

I'm trying to add the updates section of a google business profile (picture below) to my website and I can't find which API to use. I've checked both the Google Maps and the Business API's and I can't find anything that mentions access to the updates.

[image]

Comment: The use case is questionable though: you want to create new local posts manually but then access them via an API?

Answer (score 1):

The content of the local posts that already exist for a GBP location that you own can be queried using the [localPosts.list method](https://developers.google.com/my-business/reference/rest/v4/accounts.locations.localPosts/list).